# How to make sure supervisord worker (php) is running fine on GAE flex env?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, symfony4, supervisord, php-7.2

I am using symfony 4 with app engine flex env. I wrote a symfony console command which is meant to be running long term. Docs says that GAE has supervisord in place so I can use it to manage the script. How can I make sure the worker is actually running?

I've created the file `additional-supervisord.conf` with content:

```
[program:custom-worker]
command = php bin/console app:my-console-command
stdout_logfile = /dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile = /dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
user = www-data
autostart = true
autorestart = true
priority = 5
stopwaitsecs = 20
```

But I can't see anything in the log and don't know is command running properly or not. I also ssh to the instance and checked the processes - supervisord is running, but in php processes I can't see my script running. So I assume it does not work.

How can I check supervisord logs and track what's going with the worker? Would appreciate any advise.

Comment: where exactly did you store the `additional-supervisord.conf` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have stored your `additional-supervisord.conf` file correctly in the root of your project.

Give the full path to the `console` executable inside your script:

```
[program:custom-worker]
command = php %(ENV_APP_DIR)s/bin/console your:command
```

Further you can log stdout & stderr of the command to a file as follows:

```
[program:custom-worker]
command = php %(ENV_APP_DIR)s/bin/console custom:command 2>&1 1>%(ENV_APP_DIR)s/app/logs/custom.command.out.log
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! This `%(ENV_APP_DIR)s` part was confusing for me. Now the command runs ok and I see the errors, cause they just go to stdout/stderr and google catches them. 

Now I see the error because somehow old version of librdkafka was installed 0.8.6. I need 1.1.0. I understand this is different question, but maybe do you know is it possible to make GAE install the latest version of the library? In composer I just have `"ext-rdkafka": "*"` and I have 3.0.5 version of the rdkafka, but 0.8.6 of the librdkafka.